# Unable to save profile

Tags: bug, profile-page

Why would I get the error message

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:
>
> ```
> unknown error updating your profile -- please try again!
> ```

when trying to update and save my profile? Even without changing any content the error still persists.

Here's what I'm trying to save:

> I'm a senior developer for a New Zealand software development
>   company.
>
> I've been in software for over a decade, specialising in web
>   applications and Microsoft Office and leading large teams.  In my
>   spare time I [blog a
>   bit](http://mytechworld.azurewebsites.net) and do [a little
>   moonlighting](http://wheeler.kiwi.nz) as a professional consultant / developer.
>
> In whatever time I have left, I play the drums and get a bit of
>   exercise in playing squash and cricket.
>
> Follow [@Phil_Wheeler](http://twitter.com/#!/Phil_Wheeler).

Here's what I'm tracing in Fiddler:

> POST /users/hybrid/edit/15609/post HTTP/1.1

```
ProfileImageUrl https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/9178d0eacbd2a13b49729dec076eaf15?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG

ProfileImageType    61

author  phil@drum.net.nz

fkey    <a key value>

i1l <a base64 hash value>

DisplayName Phil.Wheeler

Email   phil@officeacuity.com

RealName    Phil Wheeler

WebsiteUrl  http://mytechworld.azurewebsites.net

Location    New Zealand

WoeId   

Birthday    1976/04/08

AboutMe <p>I'm a senior developer for a New Zealand software development company.</p>



<p>I've been in software for over a decade, specialising in web applications and Microsoft Office and leading large teams.  In my spare time I <a href="http://mytechworld.azurewebsites.net">blog a bit</a> and do <a href="http://wheeler.kiwi.nz">a little moonlighting</a> as a professional consultant / developer.</p>



<p>In whatever time I have left, I play the drums and get a bit of exercise in playing squash and cricket.</p>



Follow <a href="http://twitter.com/#!/Phil_Wheeler">@Phil_Wheeler</a>.

push    true

fields  

newsletter-form on
```

Comment: This error occurs when I try to edit my profile as well.

Comment: Well that's sort of a relief. Looks like I've uncovered an actual bug rather than doing something stupid.

Comment: Just add information, it works just fine for me.

Comment: No repro.  http://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will

Answer (score 7):

As I get same error, here some details:

- I am using Firefox 33.0.2 on Windows 7 64.
- The error happens entering some "About me" text (text itself does not matter) and then clicking one of the save buttons.
- I checked the network monitor and the POST request return a JSON that only contains error/general 0: "unknown error updating your profile -- please try again!"
- I can reproduce this every single try.

Comment: Might help to show an example of what was sent with the request that failed (obfuscating anything you wouldn't want to share of course)

Comment: I've added what I think is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the latest changes fixed this issue. I could "About me" now.