# How are bugs handled?

Tags: support, bug-reporting-process

I think I found a bug in SO. It also has been [reported](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272951/unable-to-save-profile) in Meta by some other user.

To me it does not look like that bug has been noticed by the responsible persons.

How do I know if that bug has been noticed, if it actually is a bug and if/when it will be fixed? Is it normal that there is no significant reaction on a bug report within a month?

Comment: I am sure the bug has been noticed.  The SE team watches meta questions, especially with the [meta-tag:bug] tag.  However, looking at the comments, at least 1 user mentioned they could not reproduce it, so it would be a difficult to reproduce bug, so it is often difficult to solve if you don't know what causes it.  If you can add something new, such as steps to reproduce, it would probably help get some movement.

Comment: Well, I basically can not change my "About me" text in SO. I get the same error message. It is that simple so I can hardly add something new :-(

Comment: The fact that it is happening to you may be something.  The fact that you can't edit your "About Me" is new information, so leaving a comment as you did is probably helpful and at worst neutral.

Comment: It doesn't happen enough, so you need to document as much as possible.  Like mentioning the browser you use, its version, what you see the server send back when you use dev tools.

Comment: Ok. I added a little more. Any more information you can think of that would be useful?

Comment: One of the `status-*` tags will be edited to the bug report "question" when the status changes, but there is no status which says that this bug is being checked out/noticed.

Comment: A couple of months back I got a glimpse of the internal bug/issue list and that showed over 4000 open issues. I'm sure yours is somehwere on that now longer list...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The community managers and developers monitor the meta sites. I would assume that the CM's check the [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions and the developers the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) ones.

Bugs will be noted. I would assume (again) that they would be prioritised in some way. If the bug doesn't cause the sites to fail or only happens occasionally/in limited circumstances then it's not going to get the attention that something that affected a lot of users would.

Similarly difficult to reproduce bugs won't get looked at as urgently. Sometimes these are marked [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) when they can be reproduced consistently.

If you come across the a problem that has already been reported check to see if you can add more details to the question that would make it easier to find (and by extension fix). Editing the question (or providing an answer) will have the effect of bumping the question to the home page, thus making it more visible both to the developers and the wider community.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it normal that there is no significant reaction on a bug report within a month?

lol… **Yes**. There are bugs that have been sitting around on meta for *years*.

Comment: Note that most longstanding bugs can go a long time without being fixed, but they're usually *acknowledged*, even if only to state that they're not worth fixing.

Comment: This is the first answer I've +1'd that started with lol. I think my life is crumbling.

Comment: Sometimes, [bugs take a really long time to review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19208/answers-posted-to-a-migrated-question-post-migration-remain-visible-and-unlocked?s=1|1.7097), @Servy.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: I think it's the first answer I've started with lol that's been +1'd ;)